# Identify 16s rRNA in metagenomes

Tags: bioinformatics

I have a database of projects downloaded from EBI metagenomes. These are fasta files containing sequence reads and have undergone basic processing (repeat masking, length cutoff - 100 etc) I want to extract sequences that are 16s reads from here. Would anybody know of good tools that do this function?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: you should ask biostar http://www.biostars.org

Answer (score 1):

We (EBI metagenomics) will be releasing a new feature soon that does just that, so if you can wait there will be an option to download sequences matching the 16S gene model. We also intend to provide taxonomic trees based on those sequences. The selection of 16S reads will be done using rRNASelector, which is an open source software tool that you can find on the internet. Hope that helps and keep an eye on EBI metagenomics (https://www.ebi.ac.uk/metagenomics) .
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use our tool called C16S (developed by Biosciences R&D, TCS Innovation Labs).

C16S: A 16S rDNA classification algorithm that uses genus-specific Hidden Markov Models (HMMs) for taxonomic classification of 16S rDNA sequences. In order to achieve high levels of accuracy, the C16S classifier incorporates a series of steps which attempt to refine the final assignment of the 16S rDNA fragment by taking into account the quality of the HMM alignment.

LINK : http://metagenomics.atc.tcs.com/C16S/